# Why is this MPI program stalling

Tags: c, mpi

```
//#define SIZE 3
void master(int n,int size)
{
for(int j=1;j<size;j++){
    MPI_Send(&n,1,MPI_INT,j,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("\n Sent %d to process %d",n,j);
    fflush(stdout);
    }
}

void slave(int size)
{
for(int j=1;j<size;j++){
    int k=0;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Recv(&k,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("\n Process %d has received %d",j,k);
    fflush(stdout);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
int la_size;
int rank;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&la_size);

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    if(rank==0)
        master(i,la_size);
    else
        slave(la_size);

}
MPI_Finalize();
printf("\nprogram finished...");
fflush(stdout);
return 0;

}
```

The program above seems simple enough but its stalling. Is it a deadlock ?
The output is :

```
     Sent 0 to process 1  
 Sent 0 to process 2  
 Sent 1 to process 1  
 Sent 1 to process 2  
 Process 1 has received 0  
 Process 2 has received 1  
 Process 1 has received 2  
 Sent 2 to process 1  
 Sent 2 to process 2  
 Process 1 has received 0  
 Process 2 has received 1  
 Process 1 has received 2
```

Comment: Why is everybody posting their code and expecting people to debug?

Comment: Because we don't understand what's going on... how things are working. Is there a better way of asking these kinds of questions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration of the loop in `main`, rank 0 is doing a single send to each of the many slave ranks, but each of the slaves is posting as many receives as there are slave ranks in total. Since there are no posted sends to match the later receives, the receivers block indefinitely, and the program hangs.

Comment: Yea, I too had thought this might be the problem.But how else can I reorganize the code ? I want to keep the code within the functions

Comment: This isn't about the functions. In each run through the outer loop, the master only interacts once with each slave, but each slave tries to interact many times with the master. Look at your loop structure.

Comment: SO I guess I should get rid of the for loop in the slave.

Comment: Oh, also, your print in `slave` lies - the loop index is not the process rank.

Comment: So basically, the whole of main() is executed on three different processes...I had not grasped this clearly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Novelocrat's answer, the correct code is actually this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#define SIZE 3

void master(int n,int size)
{
    for(int j=1;j<size;j++){
    MPI_Send(&n,1,MPI_INT,j,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("\n Sent %d to process %d",n,j);
    fflush(stdout);
    }
}

void slave(int size)
{
    int k=0,rank=0;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Recv(&k,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    printf("\n Process %d has received %d",rank,k);
    fflush(stdout);

}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    int la_size;
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&la_size);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    if(rank==0)
        master(i,la_size);
    else
        slave(la_size);

    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    printf("\nprogram finished...");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Also, if you really are sending a single value `n` to all of the slave ranks, you should probably phrase it as `MPI_Bcast` rather than a loop over `MPI_Send`.

Comment: True. I am currently just writing toy programs to help me get the hang of MPI.

Comment: Is there any debuggin environment on Linux that will send out any useful information ? I am currently just working with the terminal here. If the program hangs, I have no inkling why it happened.

Comment: The standard tool people seem to use is the commercial debugger Alinea DDT. I can't think of a common free software tool, but DDT might be gratis for personal use.